# Change event event not fired

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

what happened when a change event fired? which is the conditions that fired the change event?

```js
let i = document.querySelector('input')
i.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e))
i.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))//listener will be triggered but radio element will not be selected
i.checked = true // radio element will be selected but listener will not be triggered
i.click() //radio element will be selected and listener will be triggered
```

```html
<input name="test" type="radio" value="1">
<input name="test" type="radio" value="2">
```

So when user selecting radio nomally what did browser do?
set the checked property to true and dispatch a change event?

Answer (score 1):

A change event is fired when (particularly with `input` elements) the `value` is changed - so if you read the value, then read it after a `change` call, the two values would be different.

```js
let i = document.querySelector('input')
i.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e))
i.checked = true //Nothing happened
i.click() //event object is output
```

```html
<input name="test" type="radio" value="1">
<input name="test" type="radio" value="2">
```

Your above code isn't firing the event straightaway because you're `clicking` the `input` - and even so, because it's already selected, the `value` won't change, so nothing will happen. If you remove the `checked = true` part, it will fire, because the value is going from unchecked (not filled) to checked (filled) when you `click` the element:

```js
let i = document.querySelector('input')
i.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e))
i.click() //event object is output
```

```html
<input name="test" type="radio" value="1">
<input name="test" type="radio" value="2">
```

Comment: thank you but i just want to know why the third row does not fire an event

Comment: What do you mean "the third row"? The `i.click()` line? It does fire an event - that's why the initial data comes up, because the radio button was clicked.

Comment: i.checked = true this line. when this line of code runs the radio element  has been selected but change event not fired

Comment: Yes - that is an exception, because the `change` event only fires on user input (such as with the `click` line). When the value is manually set, then it doesn't fire.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to fired an change event other than a click() function?

Comment: @yakoutsuchimikado I do not believe so.